# Windows 7 is not allowing printer sharing

Tags: windows-7, printing

I have a newly installed Windows 7 64-bit on my computer, and I had a HP LaserJet 1012 previously installed on Windows XP 32-bit, which Windows is not allowing me to share under the upgraded OS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should turn on File- and Printersharing in your Network-Center (I don't know how it's called in english. In german it's called "Netzwerk und Freigabecenter").

Answer (score 0):

I think you network is not working correctly. if everything ok then
Open `Network and sharing center` then goto `Change Advanced Sharing Settings`.
Here check the settings for file and printer sharing on your network etc.
Password protected sharing etc.